# HiddenField in ascx cannot be used in cs call

Tags: c#, ascx

I have the following:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ctlChatBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="SignalRPrivateChat.controls.ctlChatBox" %>
<div id="chat_widnow">
    <div id="chat_title_bar"> <span class="col-sm-9 text-primary"><strong>Online Users</strong></span>
        <div id="chat_min_button"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div id="chat_box" style="display: none;overflow-y:auto;">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="chat_div"></div>
<input id="hdId" type="hidden" />
<input id="hdUserName" type="hidden" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCurrentUserName" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCurrentUserID" runat="server" />
<script src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~") %>Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~") %>signalr/hubs"></script>
<link href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~") %>styles/jquery.ui.chatbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~") %>scripts/jquery.ui.chatbox.js"></script>
<script src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~") %>scripts/chatboxManager.min.js"></script>
```

where `hdnCurrentUserName` and `hdnCurrentUserID` are `HiddenField`s, but when I call them here:

```
public partial class ctlChatBox : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["UserName"] != null && Session["UserId"] != null)
            {
                hdnCurrentUserName.Value = Session["UserName"].ToString();
                hdnCurrentUserID.Value = Session["UserId"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

I get an error of:

> The name "hdnCurrentUserName" does not exist in current context.  The
>   name "hdnCurrentUserID" does not exist in current context.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you creating your control dynamically? or did you put the control on the page?

Comment: <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCurrentUserName" runat="server" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCurrentUserID" runat="server" />

it's in the above code

Comment: I was asking where you are using this `ctrlChatBox` control, on some aspx page? how you are using? are you creating this control dynamically on aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

The ascx control has a reference to the page it's in which we could use.

```
this.Page
```

Now we need to get a control from that page. Since we know it's name you can use FindControl

```
HiddenField Info = this.Page.FindControl("hdnfldIncDesc");
```